# How to build a system that gets GPS data from 4000+ embedded devices and processes it in real time

Tags: operating-system, embedded, iot

I want to develop a system that has 4000 embedded devices that send their GPS data every 10 second to the system and this system is expected to handle this amount of data flow and required to perform mathematical operations on these data. I want this system to be open for upgrades so it should handle adding more devices. What kind of devices should I use and what kind of software should they run?
Should the devices have OS'es or not? If they should what OS should they run? Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Grossly under-specified.  SO cannot expected to design complete systems:(

Comment: "How to do my whole project" questions are never a good fit for SO. This is far too broad and cannot be answered without a detailed spec. Which is a hint: write the spec first, then worry about the design after that.

Comment: thank you for your input i'm fairly new to the site as you might have guessed, i'll try have more specific next time

Comment: First identify a suitable communication channel, then look at hardware/protocol combinations.  To what degree is the analysis of one node dependent on the others?  Modern infrastructure methods include a lot of ideas for the hard problem of sharing  interdependent work across servers but independent work is simpler to divide.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to find out how much money you will be able to invest in this.
Second, you need to hire people to provide design, manufacturing ( or sourcing ), marketing, and sales talent that you need.

If you insist on running the technical development yourself, you need to invest $30 in "The Mythical Man Month", read it, understand it, and if you don't, have some one explain it to you.   In your 5 sentences, you have broken 3 of the valuable lessons in system design from that book.